# Pygame let a class have multiple instances

Tags: python, class, pygame, instances

I need help on how to make a class have multiple instances for my Tower Defense game. I want to have the new instance appear about one second after the last one but have been stuck for hours. My code is below.

```
import pygame
import os
import time

img_path = os.path.join('test.jpg')

class redEnemy(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(img_path)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 208

    def moveEnemy(self):
        dist =  3
        if True:
            self.x += dist

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        lifes(self)


def lifeText(life):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 20)
    text = font.render("Lifes %s" % life, True, black)
    textpos = text.get_rect()
    textpos.center = (50,20)
    screen.blit(text, textpos)

def lifes(self):
    global life
    life = 50
    if self.x > 950:
        life = life - 1
        enemies.append(redEnemy())
    lifeText(life)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((960, 720))

black = (0,0,0)
enemies = []

redenemy = redEnemy()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
mapImg = pygame.image.load("mapimage.jpg")

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.update()
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.draw(screen)

    redenemy.moveEnemy()
    screen.blit(mapImg, (0,0))

    redenemy.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: what you mean exactly with multiply instances? something like that: a = redEnemy();
b = redEnemy();
print id(a),id(b)

Comment: I want the class to be able to have multiple enemies on the screen at the same time but I have no idea how to do that, I have seen online that you use lists to do it but I still get confused.

Comment: You only create one instance of redenemy `redenemy = redEnemy()`, so when you add it to a list, it will always refer to the same enemy. Also you call `enemy.update()`, but it doesn't have any such method.

Comment: So how do i fix that?

Comment: how to fix it ? normally - define `def update(self)` in you class. To have many instances simple do `instance_1 = redEnemy()` and `instance_2 = redEnemy()`, etc. You can keep all instances on list - `instances = []` and `instances.append(redEnemy())`

Comment: use `pygame.Rect()` in class to keep position and size - `self.rect` - And then you can `blit(self.image, self.rect)`. BTW: `Rect()` has special functions to check collisionts and it is used by `pygame.sprite.Group()`

Comment: Ok I will do that now and see how it goes thank you

Comment: I am sorry but I just do not understand I have done that and I just get so many errors

Comment: Add in question new code and full error message - maybe you have other mistakes or you made new mistakes.

Comment: I see mistake in `def lifes(self):` - it is not class method but you use `self`.

Comment: functions `lifes` makes no sense - it create many instances but you executes it in `redEnemy()`. Use it in main code.

Comment: `os.path.join()` with one arguments `'test.jpg'` gives `'test.jpg'` so it is useless

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you try to do in `lifes()` but rest code can looks like this:

```
import pygame
import random

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

WIDTH  = 960
HEIGHT = 720

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

FPS = 60

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

class RedEnemy(object):

    # one image for all instances
    image = pygame.image.load('test.jpg')

    def __init__(self, x, y, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        # every instance can have own image
        #self.image = pygame.image.load('test.jpg')

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.dist_x = 3
        self.dist_y = 0


    def update(self):
        # move to right side and start at left side

        if self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:      
            self.rect.x += self.dist_x
            self.rect.y += self.dist_y
        else:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def life_text(screen, life, font):

    text = font.render("Lifes %s" % life, True, BLACK)

    text_rect = text.get_rect()
    text_rect.center = (50,20)

    screen.blit(text, text_rect)

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

# - objects -

# background

map_img = pygame.image.load("mapimage.jpg")

# enemies - 10 enemies in random places

enemies = []

for i in range(10):

    x = random.randint(0, WIDTH)
    y = random.randint(0, HEIGHT)
    enemies.append(RedEnemy(x, y, screen))

# player

lifes = 50

# player = Player() # you need class Player()

# - other -

font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 20)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# - mainloop - 

running = True

while running:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # - updates -

    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.update()
        if enemy.rect.right >= screen_rect.right:
            lifes -= 1

    # - draws -

    # background

    screen.blit(map_img, (0,0))

    # enemies

    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.draw(screen)

    # other

    life_text(screen, lifes, font)

    # send buffer to monitor

    pygame.display.update()

    # - FPS -

    clock.tick(FPS)

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you furas you have explained this well to me and have taught me a lot. I am new to pygame as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

I must say, there is certainly work to be done in improving this code, but we all certainly have to start somewhere. (And I certainly am one to remain in that process of learning).

Fortunately, with a few random images I was able to run your code, and I believe I understand what you are getting at. Firstly however, I think it needs to be addressed that you ought to add

```
screen.fill((0,0,0))
```

at the beginning of your loop.

But as for the problem you intended, I believe you simply forgot to place "redEnemy" within your enemies list. By removing the odd functions in the event processor loop, and instead applying "redEnemy"'s methods on the the enemy iterator of a loop, you can get the desired result. Also, within your lives function, I saw it fit to remove the previous ship, as there was a continual stream of enemies simply pouring from one side of the screen. All the same, here is (hopefully) the code you were desiring:

```
import pygame
import os
import time

img_path = os.path.join('test.jpg')

class redEnemy(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(img_path)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 208

    def moveEnemy(self):
        dist =  3
        if True:
            self.x += dist

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
        lifes(self)


def lifeText(life):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 20)
    text = font.render("Lifes %s" % life, True, black)
    textpos = text.get_rect()
    textpos.center = (50,20)
    screen.blit(text, textpos)

def lifes(self):
    global life
    life = 50
    if self.x > 950:
        life = life - 1
        enemies.append(redEnemy())
        enemies.remove(self)
    lifeText(life)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((960, 720))

black = (0,0,0)
enemies = [redEnemy()]

redenemy = enemies[0]
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
mapImg = pygame.image.load("mapimage.jpg")

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False

    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.moveEnemy()
    screen.blit(mapImg, (0,0))

    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
```

Simply run that, and hope that your intended issue was addressed.

Comment: Thanks a lot I am new to pygame and this has shown me the order in which I need to do the code as well as solving the problem.